# WooCommerce checkout field for date input

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a few custom checkout fields using plugins before, and their markup look similar to this:

```
<label for="billing_wcj_checkout_field_1"
     class="">Date</label><input type="text" class="input-text " 
    name="billing_wcj_checkout_field_1" id="billing_wcj_checkout_field_1" 
    placeholder=""  value="" display="date" />
```

However, when I follow documentation and created custom fields like following:

```
    woocommerce_form_field(
       'date', array(
           'type' => 'text',
           'class' =>array('form-row-first'),
           'label' => __('Date'),
           'required' => false
       ), $checkout->get_value( 'date' ));
```

I am not able to set neither the display type nor the input class `"hasDatepicker"`

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add class for the input with adding this line to the array: 'input_class' => array('hasDatepicker')

```
woocommerce_form_field(
   'date', array(
       'type' => 'text',
       'class' =>array('form-row-first'),
       'label' => __('Date'),
       'required' => false,
       'input_class' => array('hasDatepicker')
   ), $checkout->get_value( 'date' ));
```

Comment: 'type' here should be 'date'